# jenkins localhost:8080 is not reached "localhost refused to connect"

Tags: jenkins

when I want to get in to Jenkins localhost:8080 (I already have account)from browser, it is not reachable something like this

"This site can’t be reached"
"localhost refused to connect."
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But, when I rerun the Jenkins war file from Cmd and keeping that specific Cmd window open, then localhost:8080 opens from browser. I did off firewall stuff but not working. any idea?

Comment: How are you starting Jenkins?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just simply and usual downloading and run it from cmd.